# aws ECS- Farget task submition pending time

Tags: aws-fargate

we have an ECS fargate cluster,that we have just created, and when testing, we noticed, that the submission of a new task takes about 2-3 minutes (PENDING to RUNNING).
since we run there a new task every minute, it's not good enough for us.
is there any way to optimize the PENDING to RUNNING time?

Answer (score 1):

This is largely dependent on the size of your container. For example I use go from scratch containers heavily so they are only about 15MB, and I get launch times from nothing -> running in roughly 15-20 seconds.

The biggest thing you can do right now to increase launch times is to reduce the size of your container.

Comment: Is this referring to the actual container size as it sits in ECR, or the memory footprint of the task? What is a good size to get fast startups in your experience?

Comment: @comfytoday Memory is not relevant (in my experience). I am talking about Container size as in the image size (storage size). And I used primarily Go containers so I could use From Scratch multistage Dockerfiles, which meant I could get like 10MB containers. But for any normal container (aside from Java) I would aim for Alpine Linux at 100-200MB.